# Función encontrar 3 pares seguidos o 3 impares seguidos en Array

Tags: javascript

Bueno estaba realizando este ejercicio en JS --->

"Crea una función que acepte un array.
Cada vez que ese array tenga 3 valores impares seguidos, imprime “¡Qué imparcial!”
y cada vez que tenga 3 pares seguidos, imprime “¡Es para bien!”.
Si no ocurre esto entonces que imprima "Array Normal"."

```js
function Par_Imp(x) {
  var count1 = 0;
  var count2 = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i] % 2 != 0) {
      // VALOR IMPAR
      count1 += 1;
      if (count1 >= 3) {
        return "¡Qué imparcial!";
        break;
      }
    } else {
      // VALOR PAR
      count2 += 1;
      if (count2 >= 3) {
        return "¡Es para bien!";
        break;
      } else {
        // SI NO HAY 3 IMPARES O 3 PARES SEGUIDOS
        return "Array Normal!";
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log("");
y = Par_Imp([2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 8]);
console.log(y);
```

No se que me falta o estoy haciendo mal. Necesito ayuda por favor. Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías volver el contador a cero del contrario (par o impar) cuando haces la evaluación, porque quieres detectar que sean "seguidos", si encuentras un par los impares tienen que volver a 0 y viceversa. El array que no cumple con ninguna condición, debería estar fuera del `for` porque queremos analizar todos los elementos del array.

```js
function Par_Imp(x) {

  var impares_seguidos = 0;
  var pares_seguidos = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i] % 2 !== 0) {
      // VALOR IMPAR
      pares_seguidos = 0; // <-- Si tuviera 2 pares ya no sirven
      impares_seguidos += 1;
      if (impares_seguidos >= 3) {
        return "¡Qué imparcial!";
        break;
      }
    } else {
      // VALOR PAR
      impares_seguidos = 0;// <-- Si tuviera 2 impares ya no sirven
      pares_seguidos += 1;
      if (pares_seguidos >= 3) {
        return "¡Es para bien!";
        break;
      }

    }
  }

  // SI NO HAY 3 IMPARES O 3 PARES SEGUIDOS
  return "Array Normal!";

}

console.log(Par_Imp([1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]));
console.log(Par_Imp([1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2]));
console.log(Par_Imp([2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1]));
```